# How can I realize a solution where data from a running Labwindows/CVI program gets stored in a Cassandra database?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, labwindows

I am using (or at least trying to use) the free DataSax distribution for Windows, and I found the C++ driver, but the only video/description I found was for VisualStudio. Is it possible to use Cassandra with Labwindows/CVI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that product is a C IDE, I think your best bet would be to use the DataStax C++ driver for Apache Cassandra. There are binary distributions for Windows, as described [here](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver#installation).